# Where are Eclipse key configurations saved on Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, key-bindings

There is no .eclipse dir under my home dir. I can't find the configuration file saving the key binding schemes. Where are they saved on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key bindings are kept in the workspace folder, under the .metadata folder (.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs, under at entry called org.eclipse.ui.commands).

If you want to transfer them between machines or workspaces, here's what you should do:

1. Go to File -> Export
2. Mark Preferences, hit OK
3. Select "Key Preferences" from the list, enter file name and hit OK

To import, follow the same procedure, selecting File -> Import.

Comment: Thanks very much. And I can't help but say it is just hidden too deep.